# In php how to echo " <?php " to the screen?

Tags: php, output

In a php script, how can you echo "<?php" to the screen? As in I want to display <?php w/o the quotes as output...actually show those five characters.

The closest Ive been able to come is this:

```
$array = array ('<','?','p','h','p',);
$count = count($array);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
echo "$array[$i] ";
}
```

which gives me the desired output but w spaces "< ? p h p"

I KNOW theres a simple way to make this happen...but require a bit of hand holding here.

I basically need the equivalent of a stackoverflow code block because any attempt to output "<?php" to the screen causes the script to interpret the word as the start of a php code block and thus the characters "<?php" wont show on the screen...

Thanks!

Comment: Your echo statement has a space within the quotes, which is why it's showing spaces in the output. But I'm not sure why you think this is any more complicated than just echoing it as a string?

Comment: My apologies. Its a php script so you can't echo it as you stated. PHP itself wont output it w/an echo, print_r or most any normal way I have attempted...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to display characters that have a special meaning for PHP or HTML in the browser, they have to be masked with [htmlspecalchars](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

```
echo htmlspecialchars('<?php',ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just echo it as a string.

```
<?php
echo "<?php";
```

`<?php` has no special meaning in PHP code, it's only used to switch from outputting text literally to parsing PHP code.

Comment: Or `<?= "<?php"; ?>`

Comment: Neither of these seem to work either. This is in a php script and when the browser sees it, it seems to be treating it AS the start of a php block...so it wont physically show on the screen...

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space  after echoing $array[$i]. like echo "$array[$i]";

Comment: Can't do that either. The result of "$array[$i]" with no space after the incrementer is "<?php" which a php script interprets as the start of a php block...and thus wont output it to the screen...

I need the equivalent of putting it in a code block like here on stockoverflow so it treats it as a LITERAL set of text instead of thinking its the start of a code block...

Comment: This is close as echo "<\?php"; shows "<\?php" on screen but if you take the \ out? php interprets it as a code block and hides it from output again...

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```php
echo "&lt;?php"
```

Here, we are using HTML entity for the `<` sign, which is `&lt;`. For this, the PHP interpreter won't interpret the `<` sign as a tag.